# What does .draw() does in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine and i am trying to draw rectangles, circles inside it, i have seen the ChartView.draw(Canvas) method but i dont know if it work on this way:

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer);
setContentView(mChartView);

Canvas a = new Canvas();
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
a.drawCircle(70, 80, 40, p);
mChartView.draw(a);
mChartView.repaint();
```

Is that code suppose to draw a green circle onto the chart ? Because the chart whit the series is being draw but not the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the Android `Canvas` uses a painter's algorithm, so **order matters**.  You probably aren't seeing the circle because the chart gets drawn afterwards and, thus, on top of the circle.  If you reverse the calls (i.e. do `mChartView.draw()` before `a.drawCircle()` you should see the circle over the top of the chart.

HTH

Comment: Anything, just an empty chart :/

Comment: Does draw() method really do that ? Because it is not much explained :/